# CORS Configuration For Rails and Angular 2 - Preflight OK but following get request is 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, http

I am having an issue with my Angular2 app consuming resources from my Rails backend.

Below is the application.rb file

```
 config.middleware.insert_before Warden::Manager, "Rack::Cors" do
   allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', 
        :headers => :any, 
        :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

And in my application_controller I have these `before` and `after` filters

```
def cors_set_access_control_headers
headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "http://localhost:3000"
headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = "Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Token"
headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
```

end

```
def cors_preflight_check
if request.method == 'OPTIONS'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS'
  headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'

  render text: "", content_type: 'text/plain'
end
```

end

I have added an JWT authentication that assigns a token to each user in my database.

```
require 'jwt'

module AuthToken
  def AuthToken.issue_token(payload)
    payload['exp'] = 24.hours.from_now.to_i
    JWT.encode(payload, Rails.application.secrets.jai_secret_key)
  end

def AuthToken.valid?(token)
    begin
        JWT.decode(token, Rails.application.secrets.jai_secret_key)
    rescue
        false
    end
  end
end
```

And the Devise strategy

```
require 'jai_auth_token'

module Devise
  module Strategies
    class JsonWebToken < Base

        def valid?
            request.headers['Authorization'].present?
        end

        def authenticate!
            success! User.find_by_id claims[0]['user_id']
        end

        protected

        def claims
            strategy, token = request.headers["Authorization"].split(' ')

            return nil if (strategy || '').downcase != 'bearer'

            AuthToken.valid?(token)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

All of this works fine, and I can retrieve the auth token when I do a `POST` request via curl or PostMan and can use that auth token to make additional requests to the backend.

I have an Angular2 Application that stores just that token and uses it to request resources. I've attempted to

When I submit a request from my application, I send the `Authorization: Bearer -token-` and I get a `200 OK` from the first preflight options request

```
General
Request URL:http://localhost:5000/users/me.json
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:5000
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

ResponseHeaders 
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:authorization,content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:1728000
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Type:text/plain
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Request-Id:8d59f888-c617-43ef-8c43-7be30a1c0343
X-Runtime:0.062901

Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization,content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:5000
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/profile
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Mobile 
Safari/537.36
```

But the following get request gives me a 500 Internal Server Error

```
Request URL:http://localhost:5000/users/me.json
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:5000
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
Content-Length:7102
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
X-Request-Id:be45013b-723a-4b7b-bea1-6b9994e91d55
X-Runtime:0.106096

Request Headers
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:Bearer AuthorizedToken
Connection:keep-alive
Content-type:application/json
Host:localhost:5000
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/profile
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Mobile 
Safari/537.36
```

And this is the Error I receive in the console

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5000/users/me.json. No 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed 
access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

I've attempted to add the headers manually, but that doesn't work. I have read this source http://restlet.com/company/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/ which has great information on CORS, and I understand that since I am sending an Authorization header it automatically goes through a preflight request. But I cannot figure out how to configure `Access-Control` to requested resources.

Comment: Seems like what you want to do is, look through the server logs on the server side to see what additional details the server might be logging about what internal server error is happening that causes the server to end up sending that 500 response. Because that 500 response indicates an internal server error on the server side that’s likely unrelated to the CORS config—which is just causing additional response headers to be sent.

Comment: The only reason you end up seeing this on the client side as a CORS error is that servers typically don’t add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to 500 responses—nor to other 5xx or 4xx responses. Instead servers typically just add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to 2xx (success) responses & maybe to 3xx (redirect) responses. If you want to have a server send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin for error responses, you typically must use some additional parameter to force that—for example, with nginx and apache, you need to add the keyword `always` to the directive you use for setting the header